# Caching not working - Jquery Load

Tags: jquery, caching

I am loading an .aspx page using jQuery's `load()` method. I have used not lot of jQuery files and css files inside that page. i have tried all caching mechanism to load the files from cache. But every time all files downloaded from server. I have used the following method no use.

Method 1:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
```

Method 2:

```
Cache-Control : Private
```

Method 3:

```
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "Private");
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can go for IndexedDb or Local Storage API to achieve caching.Here the link..

[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

[Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Hope it will help..